# How to assign value for column based on the value in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For instance, I want to create the table as below:

```
---------------------
| Column 1 | column 2 |
---------------------
| Male     | 1        |
| Female   | 2        |
-----------------------
```

Dataframe that consist only of "column 1" data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['Male','female']})
```

So, how to assign values for "column 2"?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have created your DataFrame as you did with `df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['Male','female']})`, then you could add a new column like so using the predefined index:

```
df['column2'] = df.index + 1
df
    column1 column2
0   Male    1
1   female  2
```

If you want to do this in one step when creating the DataFrame, something as follows would also work using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
column1 = ['Male','female']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': column1,
    'column2': [idx + 1 for idx, _ in enumerate(column1)]
})
```

You could also use the [pandas `apply` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) like this with an anonymous function:

```
# Showing how you could get other values with a different formula
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row["column2"] - 
                                     (row["column2"] * 0.1), axis = 1)
df
    column1 column2 column3
0   Male    1       0.9
1   female  2       1.8
```

And you could equally use a function that you define elsewhere for convenience:

```
def my_func(x):
    return int(x) ** 2

df['column4'] = df["column2"].apply(my_func)
df
    column1 column2 column3 column4
0   Male    1       0.9     1
1   female  2       1.8     4
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['Male','female'], "column2":[1,2]})
df.set_index("column1", inplace=True)
df
```

The output is as follows:

```
         column2
column1     
Male       1
female     2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas assign function.

```
column2_vec = [1,2]
df.assign(column2=column2_vec) #new column name is column2
```